# How to view and export database content?

Tags: mongodb, view, export, mongodb-3.4

I'm trying to view the actual entries, not the backend identifiers.

```
> db.<collection>.find({"_id": "486b4ca55b144b119f4551417c5798c8"}).pretty()

{
    "_id" : "486b4ca55b144b119f4551417c5798c8",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-20T05:47:06.176Z"),
    "content" : ObjectId("58f84b5a0318762cb6e230a6"),
    "digest" : "d064a874c872d75f6ab67c04d8b79b26f65f9b4f",
    "short" : "5f9b4f",
    "size" : 2374694
}
```

Also tried `mongoexport`:

```
$ mongoexport --host 127.0.0.1 --port <port> -o test --pretty --db <database> --collection <collection>
```

This also shows backend data. **I just want to see what was uploaded to the database.** The actual content itself.

Comment: See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233014/how-do-i-search-for-an-object-by-its-objectid-in-the-console

Comment: What output are you expecting - can you add an example? All of the fields in your current example are actual values stored in MongoDB. Standard JSON can only represent a subset of the data types supported by MongoDB, so perhaps you are referring  to representations like `ObjectId()` and `ISODate()` which allow you to work with additional data types (see: [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)). When you view or export content from MongoDB the extended syntax is used so that you can manipulate or import values and preserve existing data types.

Comment: What do you mean by _backend identifiers_ here?

Answer (score 1):

Commands which have been used to upload data (insert, update) to the DB are not stored anywhere normally.

You can set profile level to 2 to collect data of every operation with the [manage profiler level](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) option.

And then you could rise debug level of the [wanted component](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/) too.